# Can I check out an Artifactory repository in a Jenkins workspace?

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

Is there a way to checkout an Artifactory repository similar to a git repository so that the content of the Artifactory repository is visible in the Jenkins workspace?

For git repository we get options like checkout as a subfolder. I want to know if we can do something similar to that for Artifactory in Jenkins.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the use case for downloading the entire content of Artifactory into the Jenkins workspace? are you possibly trying to download a certain folder from Artifactory ot a group of artifacts?

Comment: I have a repo in artifactory which contains plugins I have a maven job in Jenkins which is used to create update center JSON when we pass a directory containing these plugins as an argument. Hence I wanted to know if I can check out the repo or the content of the artifactory repo in Jenkins as a subfolder in a similar way how we do for git.

Comment: @check-mate You can download the entire content of an Artifactory repository in various methods (CLI, REST API, CI plugins) as indicated in the answer. Please take into consideration this can be an inefficient operation especially if the repository contains many artifacts which takes a long time to download. Are you sure you need to download the artifacts in order to create the JSON? does it rely on the artifacts content?

Answer (score 0):

Git is the VCS and Artifactory is a repository manager and I doubt that this cannot be done. Artifactory in Jenkins is used for retrieving/downloading the packages, resolving the dependencies and deploying the build to Artifactory. If my understanding in incorrect, kindly elaborate on the use-case for better. Refer to the below wikis for better understanding,

1. https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in
2. https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Declarative+Pipeline+Syntax
3. https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Scripted+Pipeline+Syntax
4. https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/tree/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/declarative-examples